# INSERT query is failing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I'm sure it's a kickself-obvious typo, but I can't see it. I'm trying to INSERT data taken from a HTML form using POST into a MySQL database using PHP. The POST works successfully, but the query fails; I've checked the table to make sure nothing new has been inserted.

Here's the PHP code intended to run the query:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root"; //ssh don't tell
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $dbname = "asoiaf";
    $tablename = "charlist";

    $id = '3';
    $bookIntroduced = $_POST['bookIntroduced'];
    $pageIntroduced = $_POST['pageIntroduced'];
    $forename = $_POST['forename'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $oldSurname = $_POST['oldSurname'];
    $alias = $_POST['alias'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $pageIntroduced = $_POST['regnalNumber'];

    // Below is the query that fails to execute.

    $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename (
            $id, $bookIntroduced, $pageIntroduced, $title, $forename, $surname, $oldSurname, $alias, $regnalNumber
            )";

    mysql_query($query) or die("Nah, I don't feel like being helpful.");

    mysql_close($dbhandle);
}
```

And here is the structure of the table given by the DESCRIBE command:

[image]

Can anyone help me to identify the problem?

Also, if it wasn't clear, I'm new to PHP and SQL.

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API was long ago deprecated

Comment: Strawberry, maybe I've got an old version, I'm able to successfully use a SELECT query using mysql_ commands in PHP. What should I be using instead?

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Oh, I'm guessing I should be using mysqli. For some reason, I thought *that* was deprecated.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23, next to `mysql_query($query)` I wrote `or die("Nah, I don't feel like being helpful.")`. That text pops up when I run the PHP script, and when I check the table afterwards, nothing was inserted. Not an error message exactly, just proof that it isn't working.

Comment: and please use prepared statements with parameters. Bind those parameters to your input values. To get helpful error messages you should at least use die(mysql_error()) or so. And what about our friend "O'Brien" ...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: it's hard to tell what's wrong with the query w/o seeing the final query itself (i.e. `print $query`) but it looks like you're not quoting your strings for one thing (i.e. `'$title', '$forename' ..` instead of `$title, $forename ...'`)

Comment: Sorry @VMai, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. Could you explain that again?

Comment: Write out your query string when it hits die() and let us know what the final string is.

Comment: please have a look at PDOs [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and mysqli's [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Okay, I put mysql_error into the die() and it outputted `No database selected`. Guess that tells me.

Comment: Okay, @Vmai, but I'm not looking to optimise at this point, I'm just trying to get basic functionality. I'm an absolute beginner with PHP/SQL and the INSERT is challenging enough for me, before I can think about prepared statements and binding parameters.

Comment: Next you will run into your missing quotes. If you fixed that, someone will try to introduce Patrick O'Brians books ...

Comment: It will make your life easier, believe me. You don't have to worry about "Patrick O'Brian" and some such. If you're a beginner, then leave those deprecated mysql_* functions alone. Begin right from the start: use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements and parameters. It's so much more readable than concatenated sql strings. You won't regret it.

Comment: I'll get right on those newfangled functions the second I make a successful insert. Pinky promise. (I've been trying to do this for several days now and just want to get the basic principle working before I start writing good code.)

Comment: Woop, got it! Thanks @Dave and everyone else.

Comment: So is there any advantage to mysqli over PDO? Why are there two different standards?

Comment: Could somebody explain why this question is unclear? I don't see what is ambiguous about it; I was looking for help debugging an insert query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a SQL query like this is bad practice in many ways, not least because it's extremely fragile and insecure, but I think it will work if you add `VALUES` and quote the strings.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tablename VALUES (
        '$id', '$bookIntroduced', '$pageIntroduced', '$title', '$forename', '$surname', '$oldSurname', '$alias', '$regnalNumber'
        )";
```

I advise against doing this though, and I'm giving this answer just because it's the shortest path to working code. Always name your table and columns (`INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (:val1, :val2)`), and use prepared statements with mysqli.

Comment: Got it. Now I'll take y'all's advice and try to write better code :). I need to learn about prepared statements and mysqli and PDO and oh boy this learning curve needs rock-climbing equipment ^^'

Comment: +1. Some key points: 1) this INSERT statement will FAIL when new column is added to table `charlist`, or unexpected behavior when order of columns is changed. Best practice is to list the columns in the **`INSERT INTO mytab (col1, col2) VALUES (...`**.  2) **SQL Injection vulnerabilities**, best practice with the `mysql_` interface is to use **`mysql_real_escape_string`** function. 3) Better best practice (?) is to use **prepared statements** with **bind variables** with PDO or mysqli interface. 4) when dynamically created SQL text, **echo** (or printf or vardump) SQL text string for debugging

Comment: +1 for "better best practice" :). What's the difference between what mysqli and PDO do?